# Windows 8 IE 10 password field cut-off

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer, browser, operating-system

I have a problem in `IE10`, which is annoyinn. In a normal password field, you fill in your password. That's default, of course. But then, if you fill in like 25 letters and you click on a different field on the page elsewhere, the password you filled in earlier, will be cut-off to 8 letters.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

PS: on `Windows 8.1` I have a `IE 11` browser, which does not show this error in `compatibility mode`.

Comment: Siyah, this is not on-topic for StackOverflow. Questions about software issues, bugs, etc are not appropriate unless they are related directly to software development.

Comment: I thought this might me a CSS issue or something, that's why I placed it here. If it's an OS problem, then I will delete this topic.

Comment: Is it a problem with CSS you have written? Or does it happen on every page? If you think this is more of a web-dev question, then you should include tags like [tag:CSS] and [tag:HTML], but more importantly include the code you wrote so that people can reproduce it.